# Connect through squid proxy with pusher lib

Tags: java, websocket, proxy, squid, pusher

I have to connect to a websocket hosted on [pusher](https://pusher.com/), they provide a [lib](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java).

I managed to make it work on my development environment through a cntlm proxy, I have logs like this from my connectionEventListener

`New state for pusher connection: CONNECTING -> CONNECTED`

```
private final ConnectionEventListener connectionEventListener = new ConnectionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange connectionStateChange) {
        log.info("New state for pusher connection: {} -> {}",
                connectionStateChange.getPreviousState(),
                connectionStateChange.getCurrentState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String s, String s1, Exception e) {
        log.error("Some error {} - {} - {}", s, s1, e);
    }
};
```

The problem is on our pre-production environment, where it's behind a squid proxy (v.3.5.12), I get this in my logs:

```
New state for pusher connection: DISCONNECTED -> CONNECTING
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.InternalError: Should not reach here
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:181)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunnel(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:168)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.access$200(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:44)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:151)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.privilegedDoTunnel(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:148)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.connect(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:111)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.pusher.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.run(WebSocketClient.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:179)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2084)
    ... 15 more
```

My question is, did someone manage to consume websockets from pusher in java behind a squid proxy.

Update:
Problem solved, our squid proxy was missing some rules to allow connections.

Comment: The root error is *Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"* which indicates you need some kind of authentication or to have some permission set up in order to connect. Does the squid proxy have a login requirement? or does the server behind it in the pre-production environment need you to log in.

Comment: Authentication was the key, we added some rule to allow all traffic from the machine where the daemon is deployed. BUT we also had some other rule cancelling this one. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how you were able to solve the problem as I very recently had the same problem.

The URL was whitelisted in the internal squid proxy, however the problem with the current implementation of Pusher java client library is that (version 1.4.1 of `java-websocket` client by Pusher), the constructor creates an InetAddress using the host address (ws.pusherapp.com), which results in the URL being resolved to an IP address.

The library then tries to open a socket (using the proxy), to the resolved IP address, instead of opening a socket connection using the URL address. This is problematic for the proxy, as Pusher uses AWS, and the URL is dynamically resolved to a random AWS IP address.

I was able to change this behaviour by patching the `WebSocketClient.java` in the `com.pusher.java_websocket.client` package as follows

In the `public void run()` method, the original line was:

`this.socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(this.uri.getHost(), this.getPort()), this.connectTimeout);`

which I replaced with 
`this.socket.connect(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(this.uri.getHost(), this.uri.getPort()), this.connectTimeout);`

This second constructor for `InetScoketAddress` does not use the DNS to resolve the URL, and the library makes a request to Pusher servers using the URL address.